# How can I protect against cross-build injection and other dependancy management threats in Play Framework?

Tags: appsec, man-in-the-middle, java, library

I am using Play Framework's inbuilt dependancy management to download a library (HTMLUnit), to do this I add the dependancy to the build.sbt file like so:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.htmlunit" % "htmlunit" % "2.20"
```

The dependancy is then downloaded using Apache Ivy (via sbt) when I build the project.

How do I know that the downloaded dependancy is what it says it is, and also ensure it contains no malicious code?

Comment: Sourceforge is kinda malicious by default.

Comment: yea, it appears so, but its where the website for HTMLUnit sends me to download their project ([HTMLUnit Website](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)).

what choice do I really have?

Comment: at the moment I am getting the library from apache Ivy so I don't have to use source Forge, but like I said I then have to worry about cross-build injection. Not really sure what to do really, I want to use this dependancy as securely as possible as I intend to trust it with my passwords